# Rails 3 Updating an Associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 application with Loan and Transaction objects. When a Transaction is saved, I want to deduct the Transaction.amount from the Loan.amount_remaining in an after_save model method, modify_loan, in the Transaction model.

Is this the best place for this code (as opposed to calling an update method in the Loan model), and if so, how do I access and save Loan data from the Transaction model?

Here's what I've been trying to do:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :loan
belongs_to :customer
after_save :modify_loan

def modify_loan
    newamount = Loan.amount_remaining - self.amount
    if amount >= 0
        Loan.amount_remaining = newamount
    else
        nil
    end
end
end
```

However, this obviously isn't working. Does anyone know the proper way to do this? I feel like I've found some related questions on SO using Model.build, but how is this used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to update a different model (a `Loan` instead of a `Transaction`), you need to actually save your update manually. Also, you're calling `Loan` (the whole class) rather than `loan` (your transaction's loan). This should work:

```
def modify_loan
  newamount = loan.amount_remaining - self.amount
  loan.update_attributes(:amount_remaining => newamount)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense and the Transaction went through without throwing any errors. However, the Loan.amount_remaining wasn't properly updated. It appears that the self.amount was never subtracted even though the Transaction.amount showed up properly in the Transaction database. Do you know why that could be? Is self.amount the right way to do it?